# How to divide list of list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
list1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 500000.0, 500000.0, 500000.0], [0, 0, 1000000.0, 0],
         [0, 1000000.0, 500000.0, 2500000.0]]

list2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1, 4]]
```

Can we divide each element from list1 and list2?

Output should again be in lists of list.

Comment: Try to explain better what you want to achieve, what you mean with divide?

Comment: In list1 and list2 there are lists. I want to divide each list1[0] / list2[0]

Comment: Try using numpy.

Comment: So the result should look like `list3 = [[ZeroDivisionError, ZeroDivisionError, ZeroDivisionError, ZeroDivisionError], [ZeroDivisionError, ...], ...]`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Offcourse the data isn't right. But yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is commonly known as `zipwith`. Python doesn't have a builtin function to do this, but it's easy to build yourself with a list comprehension.

```
[f(a, b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]  # where f is the function to zip with!
```

This is actually a `zipwith` of `zipwith`s, though, so let's nest:

```
[[aa/bb for (aa, bb) in zip(a, b)] for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

---

EDIT: as Aran-Fey points out, `zipwith` *does* exist as `map` in Python, which makes this:

```
import functools
import operator

zipwithdiv = functools.partial(map, functools.partial(map, operator.truediv))

zipwithdiv(list1, list2)  # magic!
```

which is, admittedly, uglier than sin. But it makes my little functional heart go a-pitter patter.

Comment: *psst*: "zipwith" is just [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). (Yes, it supports multiple iterables)

Comment: @Aran-Fey oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooohh brb.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You've made me a very happy man, if perhaps encouraged me to use slightly less-Pythonic code ;)

Answer (score 5):

IIUC

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.array(list1)/list2
array([[    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan],
       [    nan,     nan,     nan,     nan],
       [    nan, 500000., 500000., 500000.],
       [    nan,     nan, 500000.,     nan],
       [    nan, 500000., 500000., 625000.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using the built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
result = []
for sub_list1, sub_list2 in zip(list1, list2):
    sub_list = []
    for a, b in zip(sub_list1, sub_list2):
        if b == 0:
            sub_list.append('DivisionByZero')
            continue
        sub_list.append(a / b)
    result.append(sub_list)
```

this will produce:

```
[['DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero'],
 ['DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero'],
 ['DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero'],
 ['DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero'],
 ['DivisionByZero', 500000.0, 500000.0, 500000.0],
 ['DivisionByZero', 'DivisionByZero', 500000.0, 'DivisionByZero'],
 ['DivisionByZero', 500000.0, 500000.0, 625000.0]]
```